# how do you convert oracle timestamp to POSIXct in R

Tags: r, oracle

Is it possible to convert an Oracle timestamp to POSIXct in R?

Sample data points:

```
1120929000000000
1120929000000000
1120929000000000
1121021000000000
1121022000000000
1121023000000000
1121021000000000
1121022000000000
1121023000000000
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: For example you can get around the timestamp format using sql `TO_CHAR` and use [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825589/convert-oracle-timestamp-to-date-time-in-r) after.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping that there was an R function that already did this without any oracle. I have done this and it converted the oracle time stamp to POSIXct type:

```
 to_char(CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(GET_UTC_TIMESTAMP(T."Timestamp", TMZDIFF) AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') AS DATE)
```